# What to do with multiple prepaid Visa cards

Tags: gift-card

I have several prepaid visa cards with around $2 on each of them.  I want to use them, but I can't find a good way to do that.  I have found two answers [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87331/transferring-balances-left-over-prepaid-credit-cards) and [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87331/transferring-balances-left-over-prepaid-credit-cards), but those only apply to physical cards.  The ones I have are from [Prepaid Digita Solutions](https://www.prepaiddigitalsolutions.com/) so I can't use them at a physical store.  What should I do with them?  Is there a way to maybe add $1.83 to my Apple account or something like that?

Comment: What makes you think those answers apply only to physical cards? I don't think that is true.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use them as 'downpayment' for anything more expensive.

For example, at Amazon, if you buy a whatchamacallit for 25 $, you can enter all your cards one by one, reducing the remaining payment, until you use a normal credit card for the remainder.
Alternatively, you can buy a gift card for the total of all your cards, and then use them to pay it off.

There is no requirement to pay the full amount from one source.

Comment: Good to know! I’ll take a look.  Unfortunately I already bought a bunch of gift cards with the remaining balance on them, but I’ll remember this for next time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer.  Jimit Raithatha posted:

> Amazon luckily allows you to buy gift cards for virtually any amount, down to even a dollar. Whenever i have some random amount left on a gift card, i just go ahead and buy an Amazon e-gift card with it. FYI - this works only with e-gift cards, not physical ones

And it worked great!